# Nested struct as members in a class

Tags: c#, .net, class, struct

I am writing a class which holds 90 integer variables. There are basically 10, but each has 3x3 attributes, making them 90. I'll explain it further.

So the 10 variables I have are: v0, v1, v2, ..., v9. Each of these has three different values, for city, county and state. Also, each of these has three different values for past, present and future.

So, a typical value would be: v3.City.Future or v7.State.Past or v8.County.Present.

I was thinking to implement a class, with 10 structs for each variable, then each of those struct has a three nested structs (for city, county and state) and each of those structs has three integer variables for past, present and future.

This is still in the conceptual phase. I tried to go with the above mentioned approach, but it is not working.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyVariable myvariable;
}

public struct MyVariable
{
    public struct National
    {
        public int Past { get; set; }
        public int Present { get; set; }
        public int Future { get; set; }
    }
    ...
}
```

Now when I instantiate the class and access the member (myclass.myvariable.National.Past), it does not get the member.

Comment: what do you mean by "it is not working"?

Comment: Sounds like it should be a class, perhaps you can post some code so we can take a look at what isn't working and be able to help with it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the answer to this:

```
public struct PeriodVars
{
    public int Past { get; set; }
    public int Present { get; set; }
    public int Future { get; set; }
}

public struct VarStruct
{
    public PeriodVars City;
    public PeriodVars County;
    public PeriodVars State;
}
```

Now the class will be:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public VarStruct v0;
    public VarStruct v1;
    ...
}
```

Once I instantiate an object of the class, I can refer it to like this:

```
objMyClass.v0.City.Past = 111;
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comment, it looks like you are mixing types and instances:

Assuming your MyVariable looks like the following:

```
public struct MyVariable
{
    public struct National
    {
        public int Past;
    }

    public National ValueForNational;
}
```

`myclass.myvariable.National` - it is a type (will not compile)

`myclass.myvariable.National.Past` - it is a member of a type (will not compile)

`myclass.myvariable.ValueForNational` - is value for a member of MyVariable member inside MyClass' variable (would compile)

`myclass.myvariable.ValueForNational.Past` - is one that you probably want...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple set of classes to accomplish that. I used classes instead of structs as there are some "gotchas" you will need to understand if you use structs.

**Unless** maybe if you describe "it is not working", I bet that your problem actually is that you are trying to use structs.

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public T Future;
    public T Present;
    public T Past;
}

public class Bar
{
    public Foo<string> City;
    public Foo<string> State;
    public Foo<string> Country;
}

public class Top
{
    public Bar v0;
    public Bar v1;
    //...
    public Bar v2;
}
```

Comment: Can you post code for "Now when I instantiate the class and access the member (myclass.myvariable.National.Past), it does not get the member."

Comment: I'm doing it like this: MyClass myclass = new MyClass();

Comment: If that is the entirety of your code, you've done nothing at all except instantiate the class.  How are you setting the values?  How are you retrieving the values?  What are you seeing?  What are you expecting to see?  We are not psychic.

Answer (score 0):

There is an initialization missing under struct MyVaribale.

**public National national;**

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myVar = new MyClass();
        myVar.myvariable.national.Past = 1;
    }
}


public class MyClass
{
    public MyVariable myvariable;
}

public struct MyVariable
{
    public National national; // This line is missing. That's why you can't access the members of the 'National' struct.

    public struct National
    {
        public int Past;
        public int Present;
        public int Future;
    }

}
```

Comment: "MyVaribale" doesn't exist.